# SSRS Image not deploying

Tags: image, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, deployment

I am experiencing a strange image deployment issue.  I am using SSRS 2014.  I have a logo in my SSRS report that is not appearing in the Sharepoint site.  I made sure that the image I am using is a JPEG.  I use this image in all of my reports and I have no deployment issues.  I have rebuilt the report several times in an attempt to identify the problem.  The image shows on the site up until I set one of my Parameters to multi-select and then it disappears.  I can always see the image in Visual Studio Preview mode.  I have found a workaround that I am not crazy about.  I added a White (blank) image that is lined up with the Logo.  For some reason this displays the Logo after deployment.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why setting a parameter to multi-select would cause the image not to deploy?

[image]

Comment: from my pass exp.. this solve my issue
http://i.stack.imgur.com/AToaz.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I checked to see if the Logo image that I copied from the other reports in the same solution was set to embedded, which it already was.  For good measure I deleted that image and added another image and set it to embedded, but it still didn't work.